# delete text on multiple lines between first pair of characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

There are a whole lot of similar questions on SO but I can't find an example similar to mine. Here's a sample file:

```
>ABCD 
blah bla
blah bla
blah bla
>123
blah bla
blah bla
>456
blah bla
```

I want to delete the text between the first pair of >. Ideally, also deleting the first >. My text spans multiple lines though. So my result should be:

```
>123
blah bla
blah bla
>456
blah bla
```

I've tried a number of sed expressions. For example:
`sed '/>/,/>/{//p;d;}' file > new`
but this deletes the text between every other >. I want to delete text between the first pair of >, including of the first one.
From another post I tried `sed '/^>/,/^\>/{/^>/!{/^\>/!d;};}' file > new`
but that deletes the lines between all > and leaves the text after the very first >, which I want to also delete.

Help really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '!c && /^>/{f=1; c=1; next} /^>/{f=0} !f' ip.txt 
>123
blah bla
blah bla
>456
blah bla
```

- `!c && /^>/` if `c` has falsey value (which it is initially) and line starts with `>`

  - set flags `f` and `c` (so, this condition will never be satisfied after the first match)
  - `next` so that other statements are skipped
- `/^>/{f=0}` clear the flag if another line starts with `>`
- `!f` print lines only if flag is not set

If you are okay with `perl` and input file is small enough to fit memory, then you can use:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/>[^>]+//' ip.txt
```

this slurps entire input as a single string, so that you can match across lines

This is possible with `GNU sed` too (assuming input doesn't have NUL character):

```
sed -zE 's/>[^>]+//' ip.txt
```

Comment: Gosh that was quick! I don't understand it but it works great - thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

sed is best for doing s/old/new on individual strings, that's all. For anything more you should use awk:

```
$ awk '/^>/{c++} c>1' file
>123
blah bla
blah bla
>456
blah bla
```

Comment: nice, but this will skip any lines before the first occurrence of `>` (but OP doesn't mention that in the question, so may be not needed to consider that case)

Comment: If the real input doesn't look like the example input provided then we can post a different solution based on whatever that input looks like once the OP modifies the example to show it. I suspect every block (and so the whole input file) does start with `>foo` though just like in the example.

Comment: Every file of mine does start with > though the following text on that line changes. Good distinction though for future use!

Comment: Just curious - why wouldn't you use this for the present rather than just for the future? Doesn't it do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^>/{:a;n;//!ba;:b;p;n;bb};p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

On the presentation of a line beginning `>`, throw away all subsequent lines until another line beginning `>`.

Print this line and all further lines until the end of the file.

N.B. All lines before the  first beginning `>` are printed also.